# OutofMemory Exception occuring with OpenJPA

Tags: out-of-memory, openjpa, recursive-query

I am getting an out of memory error when I attempt to pull back a huge tree of objects using openJPA...
what can I do to alleviate this... Here is a bit of my methodology...

I search for an entity...
This entity should have child entities associated with it (which are esesntially the same entity)... So I include a List of children with it...

```
private List<Organization> childOrgsTree = new ArrayList<Organization>();
```

So the entity is an organization and I include a list of organizations with this entity... Now I have a named native query that gets every child of this particular entity.  I recursively loop through each of those children and find each child of that entity...  Making that same named native query call probably thousands of time.  Constructing the child tree objects recursively.  Now, this seems to work, until I run into an out of Memory Exception... I am a little flumoxed how I can get around this little problem?  I obviously could just increase the memory allocated to the process, but I fear that would be a bandaid.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am a little flumoxed how I can get around this little problem?

You have two options, hold on to less memory in your application code, or increase the JVM heap size.

Comment: Hmmm... Maybe, I was looking at this link http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.3/apache-openjpa-1.0.3/docs/manual/ref_guide_caching.html
And http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.4/apache-openjpa-1.0.4/docs/manual/ref_guide_pc_scos.html#ref_guide_pc_scos_proxy_
I am hoping that one of them will give me the answer I seek

Comment: I have no clue how no clue how the OpenJPA user manual is going to solve the problem that you are pulling too much data into the JVM?

Comment: I was actually hoping for some kind of paging mechanism... But your sarcasm was priceless

Comment: Unfortunately I am not a mind reader. Perhaps you should have asked about a paging mechanism?

Comment: paging, caching, I am really open to any solution.

Comment: I still stand by my original answer. Hold on to less memory. Caching isn't going to solve this problem, and even paging won't help the fact that you're holding on to too much memory.